# Store "constants" without reevaluating them in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm tinkering with a program evaluating optimal yahtzee play. Something that will need to be done often is performing a given task for every possible roll. The following function creates a list that contains all possible rolls, which will be mapped over frequently.

```
type Roll = [Int]

rollspace :: Int -> [Roll]
rollspace depth = worker [[]] 0
      where m xs n      = map (\e -> n:e) xs
            addRoll xs  = m xs 1 ++ m xs 2 ++ m xs 3 ++ m xs 4 ++ m xs 5 ++ m xs 6
            worker xs i = if i == depth then xs else worker (addRoll xs) (i+1)
```

This function works as intended, and produces a list of 7776 items when run with a `depth` of `5`. However, it seems terribly inefficient to generate the list of all rolls at a given depth any time it is needed, especially because the depths will only be in the range `1-5`. Is there and way to store the `rollspace` lists for the needed depths and reference them without reevaluating, or does Haskell compile away this issue?

Comment: Haskell is lazy, that means that if you store `rollspace 2` somewhere, it will *not* evaluate it. Only if you *need* it it will evaluate it, and only the parts that are necessary. So if there is a list and you access the second item to print that, and the second item does not depend on the first, it will not evaluate the first.

Comment: Separately from your question: `rollspace depth = replicateM depth [1..6]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there and way to store the rollspace lists for the needed depths and reference them without re-evaluating?

Yes, sure, and it's even technology you already know.

```
rollspace5 :: [Roll]
rollspace5 = rollspace 5

rollspace4 :: [Roll]
rollspace4 = rollspace 4
-- etc.
```

If it's important that you have a "function-like" object that accepts a number as input -- i.e. rather than knowing statically that you want depth 5 -- you have a few options, including:

```
rollspaceStored :: Int -> [Roll]
rollspaceStored 5 = rollspace5
rollspaceStored 4 = rollspace4
-- etc.
rollspaceStored other = rollspace other

rollspaceMap :: IntMap [Roll]
rollspaceMap = fromList [(n, rollspace n) | n <- [0..5]]
```

There are also packages on Hackage for memoization more generally; that search term should be enough to find them.